# Error installing geopandas in python on mac m1

Tags: pip, geopandas, pyproj, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to install geopandas on my M1 mac and I'm running into errors

I tried to pip install all the dependencies individually but where I'm tripping up is in the install of pyproj.

I installed PROJ using brew install proj and that worked fine

When I try to pip install pyproj, I get the follow error

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyproj  

Building wheel for pyproj (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyproj (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      PROJ_DIR is set, using existing PROJ installation..
      
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'pyproj._geod' extension
      pyproj/_geod.c:704:10: fatal error: 'geodesic.h' file not found
      #include "geodesic.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyproj
Failed to build pyproj
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyproj, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: File a bug report, I think that's easiest. For a question here, extract a [mcve].   In short, you are missing a library's header file.

Answer (score 17):

At the moment, installing geopandas on M1 macs can be achieved via conda or pip+homebrew.

GeoPandas itself is written in pure Python, so there is no issue running that on any architecture. However, it depends on other libraries that are written in other languages (C, C++) that need to be compiled specifically for M1 chips. While you could compile it yourself, I am not going to cover this option as it is not user friendly.

There are three possible sources of required libraries - pip wheels, conda-forge, and Homebrew.

When a Python package requires C dependency, it can create wheels with the dependency compiled for each system and chip architecture. See for example pygeos - https://pypi.org/project/pygeos/#files. What you need is `*macosx_11_0_arm64.whl` . If your package doesn't offer it, you have to find another way of installing than `pip`. Since  GeoPandas requires shapely and fiona (among others) that do not have these wheels, you should look elsewhere - either on conda-forge or Homebrew. Below are both options tested as of today.

### Conda and conda-forge way (recommended)

Conda-forge currently has all packages geopandas needs

Install M1 version of miniforge or mambaforge. It can be downloaded from here - https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge.

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas pygeos
```

Note: if you install x86 (Intel) version of conda, it will run under Rosetta2 and install all packages using x86 architecture, meaning that everything will run under emulation. Try to avoid that.

### Pip and Homebrew way

Homebrew can install C libraries compiled for M1. Python packages will find and use them.

Using an environment with Python 3.9

Install shapely:

```sh
brew install geos
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/
pip install shapely
```

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed for shapely to find GEOS installation.

Install fiona:

```
brew install gdal
pip install fiona
```

Install pyproj:

```
brew install proj
pip install pyproj
```

Install geopandas and pygeos for speedups:

```sh
pip install pygeos
pip install geopandas
```

Note that this is a copy&paste of my own explanation given in https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1816#issuecomment-1003093329.

Comment: thanks. the pip approach is the process I followed. Where I'm getting stuck is on pyproj. I'm able to "brew install proj" successfully but I get an error on the  "pip install pyproj" step. this is the traceback I pasted in my original question. any ideas on how I can get around it?

Comment: PROJ seems to be incorrectly installed for some reason. Check if `PROJ_DIR` actually points to PROJ.

Answer (score 1):

Related https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/1027

I was stuck with the same problem, I also tried setting the environment values for `PROJ_DIR, PROJ_LIBDIR, PROJ_INCDIR` but perhaps setting the values is causing the error, so closed the terminal and tried again and was able to install correctly

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on maxOS Monterey with M1 architecture in March 2023. The difference is that I use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management.

I followed [@martinflies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71139156/1663382) process and it also worked for Poetry. Shown below with minor syntax changes for Poetry.

#### Poetry and Homebrew way

Homebrew can install C libraries compiled for M1. Python packages will find and use them.

Using an environment with Python 3.9

###### Install shapely:

```
brew install geos
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/
poetry add shapely
```

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is needed for shapely to find GEOS installation.

###### Install fiona:

```
brew install gdal
poetry add fiona
```

###### Install pyproj:

```
brew install proj
poetry add pyproj
```

###### Install geopandas and pygeos for speedups:

```
poetry add pygeos
poetry add geopandas
```

##### Using pyproject.toml file

```
brew install geos gdal proj
```

pyproject.toml (versions are * to allow newest dependency versions if you use this at a later date) :

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Anon <anon@ymo.us>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
shapely = "*"
fiona = "*"
pyproj = "*"
pygeos = "*"
geopandas = "*"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
jupyter = "^1.0.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```